# Sql server 2005 torn page,error 424

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

My Dell pc failed;it was blue screen.I fixed that problem by formatting and reinstalling OS and other software that i have been using.Then I recoved my db designed using sqlserver 2005 and other files using recovery tools ;Easy Recovery 6.0.

The problem is : When I try to attach the recovered file(lpdb.mdf),It can not attached.The operation fails with the following message :

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Attach database failed for Server 'SAPC'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: torn page (expected signature: 0x55555555; actual signature: 0x4c093c91). It occurred during a read of page (0:0) in database ID 0 at offset 0000000000000000 in file 'F:\Recovered\lpdb_log.LDF'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 824)

Is there any who can help me?

I thank you!

Dejene.

### Edit

By gbn from other closed question:

Hi mrdanny,

I tried the way you suggested me. The problem is unresolved.

Error is reported : Message One or more files do not match the primary file of the database. If you are attempting to attach a database, retry the operation with the correct files. If this is an existing database, the file may be corrupted and should be restored from a backup.

Is there an alternative solution that i should try? I am going to redesign the database.Please save my time!

Comment: When are you getting that error?  Did you rename the log file, and then try attaching the database using the stored procedure that I referenced below?

Answer (score 4):

1. Have you a good backup?
2. Given it says page (0:0), then I refer you to point 1
3. Use [emergency mode](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/CHECKDB-From-Every-Angle-EMERGENCY-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort.aspx) and hope for the best. Paul Randall *wrote* DBCC CHECKDB...

Comment: Excellent advice here.  We had this exact problem, did the repair and found we lost records.  Had to go back to slightly stale backups.

Answer (score 1):

The torn page is in the log file, so rename the log file and use the sp_attch_single_file_db procedure to attach the mdf and generate a new transaction log file.